# async and promise - is this correct usage?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, promise, future

I am learning multithreading and I have found one example which bothers me. (I am not the author of this code).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
using namespace std;

void testFunc(std::promise<int> &result, std::promise<bool> &done)
{
    // other... 

    result.set_value(10);           
    done.set_value(true); 

    // other.... 
}

int main()
{

    std::promise<int>       resultPromise;
    std::promise<bool>      donePromise;

    std::future<int>    resultFuture = resultPromise.get_future();
    std::future<bool>   doneFuture = donePromise.get_future();

    std::async(std::launch::async, testFunc,
               std::ref(resultPromise), std::ref(donePromise) );    // line A

    bool done = doneFuture.get();                   // line B
    int result_testFunc = resultFuture.get();       // line C

    // do other things with result_testFunc

    return 0;
}
```

It seems to me that it would be easier to use `future` which is returned by `async`. We can return value in `testFunc()` and then use `get()` on mentioned `future`. We don't need to create `resultPromise` and `donePromise`.

1. Does above snippet presents proper usage of `future` and `promise`? (in theory)
2. Will `get()`, called on line B, block until the thread function `testFunc()` has completed and exited?

Comment: I don't know where you brought this code from, but.. 1) The person who wrote it doesn't understand how to use `promise`/`future`. 2) `std::future` and `std::async` have been a bad idea to begin with. `async` launches a new thread for each invocation, `future` blocks on destruction. 3) use something modern and normal, like my [concurrencpp](https://github.com/David-Haim/concurrencpp) . blocking a thread to consume asynchronous values is so 10 years ago, we have `co_await` now.

Comment: @DavidHaim 2) is not entirely correct. For example on latest msvc implementation std::async uses a thread pool.

Comment: which is against the standard anyway, because the standard *mandates* the implementation to create a new thread. plus, the win32 threadpool is one of the crappiest I've seen.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `std::future`. But yeah, you never know how exactly `std::async` is implemented. For this reason it's better to submit [`packaged_task`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task)s to your own thread pool. In addition, when scheduling N jobs on N processors, the Nth job can run synchronously (in the caller thread). The reduction in context switching from this seemingly minor improvement can lead to an overall 10-15% speedup.

Comment: `std::async` returns a `future` with `[[nodiscard]]`, that call itself blocks, because `future` would block on destruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this example, it would certainly make more sense to return a value in the lambda provided to `std::async`.

In general, futures and promises are meant to facilitate asynchronous programming. Where waiting should typically be avoided or at least reduced.

To avoid waiting altogether, you could use the experimental `std::future::then` to assign a **continuation** function that will process the result of the first lambda.

Alternatively you could use `co_await` which basically wraps `std::future::then` behavior in a more readable syntax. But in my opinion it is better if you first have a solid understanding of the `std::future::then` mechanism.

To reduce waiting, you can utilize the posting thread (main) to do something useful while the asynchronous task is running in the background.

Note that `co_await` is quite new to C++ and supported only on certain compilers.
`std::future::then` is still in experimental stages, but available at least on msvc.

As for your specific questions:

> Does above snippet presents proper usage of future and promise? (in
> theory)

The code will work, but the usage pattern is not ideal as explained.

> Will get(), called on line B, block until the thread function
> testFunc() has completed and exited?

Yes. It will block until testFunc has completed its work on a background thread.

Comment: `std::future::then` is not (yet) a part of the C++ standard.

Comment: @interjay edited to answer to emphasize that. Thanks.

Comment: `Note that co_await is quite new to C++ and supported only on certain compilers.` - it's supported by all 3 big compilers (MSVC, Clang, GCC)

Comment: @DavidHaim on versions that have little to none presence in mass industry and not all platforms (and C++20 pretty much screwed its own support on some non-x86 systems)